# Should I use Enums or Typedarray for drawables

Tags: android, enums

I load images in my application. I have been using an Enum with the images, but I have read somewhere that it's not memory wise to use enums so would it be better to Store them TypedArrays and retrieve them in my adapter as an array?

Enum class

```
public enum TeamLogos {

ONE(R.drawable.t1),
TWO(R.drawable.t2),
THREE(R.drawable.t3),
FOUR(R.drawable.t4),
FIVE(R.drawable.t5),
SIX(R.drawable.t6),
SEVEN(R.drawable.t7),
EIGHT(R.drawable.t8),
NINE(R.drawable.t9),
TEN(R.drawable.t10),
ELEVEN(R.drawable.t11),
TWELVE(R.drawable.t12),
THIRTEEN(R.drawable.t13),
FOURTEEN(R.drawable.t14),
FIFTEEN(R.drawable.t15),
SIXTEEN(R.drawable.t16),
SEVENTEEN(R.drawable.t17),
EIGHTEEN(R.drawable.t18),
NINETEEN(R.drawable.t21),
TWEENTY(R.drawable.t22),
TWENTYONE(R.drawable.t23),
TWENTYTWO(R.drawable.t24),
TWENTYTHREE(R.drawable.t25),
TWENTYFOUR(R.drawable.t26),
TWENTYFIVE(R.drawable.t27),
TWENTYSIX(R.drawable.t28),
TWENTYSEVEN(R.drawable.t29),
TWENTYEIGHT(R.drawable.unkown),
TWENTYNINE(R.drawable.t30);



private static final String TAG = "Avatar";

private final int mResId;

TeamLogos(@DrawableRes final int resId) {
    mResId = resId;
}

@DrawableRes
public int getDrawableId() {
    return mResId;
}
```

retriving them in my adapter

```
private static final TeamLogos[] mTeamLogos = TeamLogos.values();
```

setting the drawable

```
        left.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, mTeamLogos[childObject.getHomeIcon()].getDrawableId(), 0, 0);
```

Comment: Post the code, how you are using enums with the images

Comment: @Jedil done, I updated it

Comment: You could store them just in an int array?

Comment: Like in every adapter I want to use them in?

Comment: but what is the profit from using Enum instead of just making
`int[] array = new int[]{R.drawable.xyz1, R.drawable.xyz2 ... }`

Comment: to add to what @Jedil is saying, it might be best to store them as a [typed array](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) in arrays.xml.

Comment: @Jedil Cause I use those images in four different adapters, doesn't make the code clean to write the array four times, otherwise no difference

Comment: You could make this `static` or better way is to use xml array like Adeeb said.